# Add a route to ruby on rails to test some code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I have a Ruby on Rails project.  I am trying to create a new /positions page that will use Angular.  I want to be able to test the new code and the old code at the same time, so I can't overwrite the current function.

To get to my old code, I simply go to /positions, this executes the code in the positions controller in the index function.

I'd like to create a new method in /positions called "angular" so that when I got to /positions/angular I can get to it.  If I just go to /positions I can still get to my current index function.

How do I setup my route?  Also, is there a better way to do this?
Here is how it currently looks:

```
resources :positions do
get 'add_edit', on: :collection
member do
  get 'angular',    action: :angular,    as: :angular
  get 'add_transaction/:order_number',    action: :add_transaction,    as: :add_transaction
  get 'remove_transaction/:order_number', action: :remove_transaction, as: :remove_transaction
end
```

end

Comment: looks good to me, what is your actual question? :)

Comment: I want to be able to get to a new function called "angular".  If I try to go to positions/angular it tries to go to the "show" method and thinks the id is "angular".  "Angular" will basically be a copy of "index" but with a few things changed.

Comment: Because the show route expects a url like `/positions/:id` where `:id` can be any string (not just numbers), you need to use a route that does not match the pattern "/positions/XXX". Use different pattern for your route  (use better names than these): /positions/whatever/angular or /positions_angular or /whatever

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I ended up just adding the following to the routes, making a new angular function and a new angular view.   get 'positions_angular' => 'positions#angular'

Answer (score 0):

I added this to routes.rb

```
       get 'positions_angular' => 'positions#angular'
```

I added an angular function to my positions_controller.rb, and created an angular view.